# How can I access an object property inside the object while inside a function in the property without a getter?(javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have this code where I want all my code to be inside one main object without exeptions:

```
var inputs = [];

var Ivh = {
  addInput: (input, display, message, regex) => {
    inputs.push([input, display, message, regex, input.value]);
  }
}
```

yet this wouldn't work:

```
var Ivh = {
  inputs: [],
  addInput: (input, display, message, regex) => {
    inputs.push([input, display, message, regex, input.value]);
  }
}
```

How would I convert the inputs variable into a property for Ivh? I tried finding ways to access an object's property from inside the object with getters and this but none of them would work. ie.(this wouldn't allow me to call the Ivh's addInput function and getters don't take arguments)

Comment: uhh, make it a property and use `this.inputs.push()` in the function? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunatly, that doesn't work...

Comment: Umm yes it does. *edit* in your edit you left out `this.` in the expression: it must be `this.inputs.push()`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized but the problem is it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '`push`')" and console.loging `this.inputs` returns `undefined`

Comment: What exactly are you doing with that `addInput()` method? Are you attaching it as an event listener or something like that? In that case, you have to **bind** it to the `Ivh` object before attaching it.

Comment: Either qualify `inputs` as `Ivh.inputs` or change `addInput` to have a dynamic `this` by not using an arrow function and then qualify `inputs` as `this.inputs`.

Comment: As an onkeyup in an input tag